# How to use HttpMethodOverrideMiddleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

According to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1), we can use

```
app.UseHttpMethodOverride();
```

in our Configure function in startup.cs which should allow an incoming POST request to override the GET method by supplying a header `X-Http-Method-Override:"GET"` in a POST request.

However, we have no idea how this `UseHttpMethodOverride` extension method can work after we have inspected the original source code from Microsoft.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Middleware/HttpOverrides/src/HttpMethodOverrideMiddleware.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides
{
    public class HttpMethodOverrideMiddleware
    {
        private const string xHttpMethodOverride = "X-Http-Method-Override";
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly HttpMethodOverrideOptions _options;

        public HttpMethodOverrideMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IOptions<HttpMethodOverrideOptions> options)
        {
            if (next == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
            }
            if (options == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
            }
            _next = next;
            _options = options.Value;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (HttpMethods.IsPost(context.Request.Method))
            {
                if (_options.FormFieldName != null)
                {
                    if (context.Request.HasFormContentType)
                    {
                        var form = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
                        var methodType = form[_options.FormFieldName];
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(methodType))
                        {
                            context.Request.Method = methodType;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var xHttpMethodOverrideValue = context.Request.Headers[xHttpMethodOverride];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xHttpMethodOverrideValue))
                    {
                        context.Request.Method = xHttpMethodOverrideValue;
                    }
                }
            }
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

As it doesn't map the POST data from requestBody to the GET's queryString, our GET controller can't get the value from client. How does this thing work? Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpMethodOverrideMiddleware` is mainly override for HTTP methods excluding both `GET` and `POST`. It's usually used for `PUT`, `DELETE`, `PATCH`, etc. So I  believe it is not recommended to use with `GET` method.

Answer (score 0):

The model binding isn't strictly associated with the HTTP method being used.

> By [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sources) model binding gets data in the form of key-value pairs from the following sources in an HTTP request:
>
> 1. Form fields
> 2. The request body (For controllers that have the [ApiController] attribute.)
> 3. Route data
> 4. Query string parameters
> 5. Uploaded files